# issue getting the value from database to combobox

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This is my controller:

```
<?PHP
class combobox extends CI_Controller 
{

    function dynamic_combobox()
    {

        $this->load->model('combobox_model');       
        $data['college'] = $this->combobox_model->getcollege();
        $this->load->view('header', $data); 
        $this->load->view('left_menu', $data);  
        $this->load->view('manage_user', $data);    
        $this->load->view('footer', $data); 
    }

}

?>
```

This is my model:

```
$this->db->get('colleges'); 
$data = array(); 
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){ $data[] = $row; } 
} 
$query->free_result(); 
return $data;
```

This is my view:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url(''); ?>" method="post">
    College

    <select name="id" id="id" style="width: 350px;">
        <option class="droplist">Please select colleges</option>
        <?
            if (count($college)>0) 
            {

                foreach ($college as $row) 
                {
                    echo "<option value='". $row['college_id'] . "'>" . $row['college_name'] . "</option>";
                }
            }
        ?>

    </select>
    Courses
    <select>
        <!--<option>UG</option>
        <option>PG</option>-->
    </select>
    <input class="button" type="button" value="Refresh"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if it works or not, Your model:

```
$rs = $this->db->get('colleges'); 
$data = array(); 
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
    $data   = $rs->result_array();
} 
$query->free_result(); 
return $data;
```

Your View:

```
if (count($college)>0){
    foreach ($college as $row){
    echo "<option value='". $row['college_id'] . "'>" . $row['college_name'] . "</option>";
    }
}
```

Edit 1:

```
$arr[]    = array('college_id' => '1', 'college_name' => 'Nadar Saraswathi College of Engineering and Technology', 'status' => '1', 'created_by' => '1', 'modified_by' => '1', 'created_date' => '2012-09-30 22:51:25', 'modified_date' => '2012-09-30 22:50:28' );
print_r($arr);
echo "<select>";
foreach ($arr as $row){
    echo "<option value='". $row['college_id'] . "'>" . $row['college_name'] . "</option>";
    }
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: not working friends... combobox displayed result is " . $row['college_name'] . "...doesn't get a value.any other solution.

Comment: Try, `print_r($data);die;` before `return $data;` and see the array if its fetching the rows correctly.

Comment: hi saha put print_r($data);die; and after refresh the page,but result is same...issue not fixed

Comment: I wanted you to `print` the tuples you get in your `$data`. Its a way of debugging not an answer. Just see that you are returning the correct array from your model to your controller.

Comment: hi saha db value is printed at top of page...but doesn't set the value to combobox..

Comment: Im asking you to post your array structure here by editing your question once again.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [college_id] => 1 [college_name] => Nadar Saraswathi College of Engineering and Technology [status] => 1 [created_by] => 1 [modified_by] => 1 [created_date] => 2012-09-30 22:51:25 [modified_date] => 2012-09-30 22:50:28 ) )

Comment: Please see the above edit. Its based upon your array structure.

Comment: Hi Niloy still now i received same problem. I taken this coding from one link. that coding is working fine on separately, if i integrated into my project, i received this problem. Please guide me..

Comment: Change this line :  `<form action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" method="post">`  to `<?php echo form_open('controller_name/method_name')?>`and put your controller name and method name appropriately. @Ganesh

Comment: Hi saha sorry still problem not fixed.so can i send my source or project link for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed to add `$query` in your model

```
$query=$this->db->get('colleges'); //<---- here notice $query=
$data = array(); 
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
  $data=$query->result_array();  //<--no need of using loop as you are already looping it in you view
} 
$query->free_result(); 
return $data;
```

Comment: not working friends... combobox displayed result is " . $row['college_name'] . "...doesn't get a value.any other solution.

Comment: make sure you are getting the value in $row.. print_r($data).. and check if you are getting the datas from DB or not

Comment: hi bipen i can't understand...where to put print_r($data)?

Comment: put it before `return $data`; so the codes will be `print_r($data);exit;return $data;` and refresch you page.. this should give you the datas

Comment: hi bipen put print_r($data);exit; and after refresh the page,but result is same...

Comment: This is my route file:$route['combobox/dynamic_combobox'] = "combobox/dynamic_combobox";
$route['user/view'] = "user/view";
$route['default_controller'] = "user";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: Hi bipen still now i received same problem. I taken this coding from one link. that coding is working fine on separately, if i integrated into my project, i received this problem. Please guide me

Comment: hmm ok.. first of all make sure you are getting the datas from DB or not for that .. in you controller after this line ..` $data['college'] = $this->combobox_model->getcollege();` add `print_r($data['college']);exit;` to check if you are getting datas here or not

Comment: Hi bipen i got data from database.I added print_r($data['college']);exit; after result is following array structure.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [college_id] => 1 [college_name] => Nadar Saraswathi College of Engineering and Techno [status] => 1 [created_by] => 1 [modified_by] => 1 [created_date] => 2012-09-30 22:51:25 [modified_date] => 2012-09-30 22:50:28 ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [college_id] => 1 [college_name] => Nadar Saraswathi College of Engineering and Techno [status] => 1 [created_by] => 1 [modified_by] => 1 [created_date] => 2012-09-30 22:51:25 [modified_date] => 2012-09-30 22:50:28 ) )

Comment: hi bipen combobox displayed result is " . $row['college_name'] . "...i got array structure only.